# Interleaving split strings as a list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I need to interleave to strings into a singe list, yet am at a loss re how to do it.

The code I'm using currently is this (I haven't gotten very far):

```
 public PartialViewResult Interleave(string details, string ids)
    {
            List<string> detailList = details.Split(',').ToList();
            List<string> idlist = ids.Split(',').ToList();
            return PartialView("_ConceptDetail1", detailList)     
    }
```

Is there a standard way to interleave the lists?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: You don't need .ToList on your temporary local variables. Give sample input and expected output and it will be easier to help you achieve exactly what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want to zip both together, you can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) then:

```
String[] details = details.Split(',');
String[] ids = ids.Split(',');
List<String> idDetails = ids.Zip(details, (id, detail) => id + " " + detail)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Zip`'s implementation, I supposed I would make my own extension method :

```
    static IEnumerable<T> Interleave<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
        {
            using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator2 = second.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext() && enumerator2.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
                    yield return enumerator2.Current;
                }
            }
        }
        yield break;
    }
```